# Printing a given number in larger size in console using c

Tags: c

**PLEASE HELP**
Where did I make mistake in the following program?
It is not giving the expected output. I have found some solutions to this problem but they are using different logic. I want to know what is the problem with the following logic.
I did a dry ran according to this logic, I didn't find any problem there. I am really very confused.

```
# include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char zero[5][5] = {
        "#####",
        "#   #",
        "#   #",
        "#   #",
        "#####"
    };
    char one[5][5] = {
        "    #",
        "    #",
        "    #",
        "    #",
        "    #"
    };
    char two[5][5] = {
        "#####",
        "    #",
        "#####",
        "#    ",
        "#####"
    };
    char three[5][5] = {
        "#####",
        "    #",
        "#####",
        "    #",
        "#####"
    };
    char four[5][5] = {
        "#   #",
        "#   #",
        "#####",
        "    #",
        "    #"
    };
    char five[5][5] = {
        "#####",
        "#    ",
        "#####",
        "    #",
        "#####"
    };
    char six[5][5] = {
        "#####",
        "#    ",
        "#####",
        "#   #",
        "#####"
    };
    char seven[5][5] = {
        "#####",
        "    #",
        "    #",
        "    #",
        "    #"
    };
    char eight[5][5] = {
        "#####",
        "#   #",
        "#####",
        "#   #",
        "#####"
    };
    char nine[5][5] = {
        "#####",
        "#   #",
        "#####",
        "    #",
        "#####"
    };

    char userInput[3] = "356";
    int n = 3,i,j;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            switch(userInput[j])
            {
                case '0':
                    printf("%s ",zero[i]);
                    break;
                case '1':
                    printf("%s ",one[i]);
                    break;
                case '2':
                    printf("%s ",two[i]);
                    break;
                case '3':
                    printf("%s ",three[i]);
                    break;
                case '4':
                    printf("%s ",four[i]);
                    break;
                case '5':
                    printf("%s ",five[i]);
                    break;
                case '6':
                    printf("%s ",six[i]);
                    break;
                case '7':
                    printf("%s ",seven[i]);
                    break;
                case '8':
                    printf("%s ",eight[i]);
                    break;
                case '9':
                    printf("%s ",nine[i]);
                    break;
            }
            
        }
        printf("\n");
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You’re not accounting for the string terminator in your arrays - they need to be `char [5][6]`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. While I think, John Bode is right, you forgot to tell us what is your expected output and what wrong output you get. That is very important information and should be added to very question. Simply stating "not giving the expected output" is not a useful description.

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/), [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c), the documentation of your compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...). Invoke GCC as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: Testing this code with gcc on linux works as expected

Comment: assuming expected output is printing a large 356 composed of hash signs

Comment: BTW, you could code a graphical user interface program using [GTK](http://gtk.org/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I think there is other reason of this exercise

Comment: @JohnBode post your comment as a f.en answer.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I took John Bodes comment to form an answer.

```
# include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char zero[][6] = {
        "#####",
        "#   #",
        "#   #",
        "#   #",
        "#####"
    };
    char one[][6] = {
        "    #",
        "    #",
        "    #",
        "    #",
        "    #"
    };
    char two[][6] = {
        "#####",
        "    #",
        "#####",
        "#    ",
        "#####"
    };
    char three[][6] = {
        "#####",
        "    #",
        "#####",
        "    #",
        "#####"
    };
    char four[][6] = {
        "#   #",
        "#   #",
        "#####",
        "    #",
        "    #"
    };
    char five[][6] = {
        "#####",
        "#    ",
        "#####",
        "    #",
        "#####"
    };
    char six[][6] = {
        "#####",
        "#    ",
        "#####",
        "#   #",
        "#####"
    };
    char seven[][6] = {
        "#####",
        "    #",
        "    #",
        "    #",
        "    #"
    };
    char eight[][6] = {
        "#####",
        "#   #",
        "#####",
        "#   #",
        "#####"
    };
    char nine[][6] = {
        "#####",
        "#   #",
        "#####",
        "    #",
        "#####"
    };
    //found another spot that's dangerous
    char userInput[] = "356";
    int n = 3,i,j;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            switch(userInput[j])
            {
                case '0':
                    printf("%s ",zero[i]);
                    break;
                case '1':
                    printf("%s ",one[i]);
                    break;
                case '2':
                    printf("%s ",two[i]);
                    break;
                case '3':
                    printf("%s ",three[i]);
                    break;
                case '4':
                    printf("%s ",four[i]);
                    break;
                case '5':
                    printf("%s ",five[i]);
                    break;
                case '6':
                    printf("%s ",six[i]);
                    break;
                case '7':
                    printf("%s ",seven[i]);
                    break;
                case '8':
                    printf("%s ",eight[i]);
                    break;
                case '9':
                    printf("%s ",nine[i]);
                    break;
            }
            
        }
        printf("\n");
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a function which allows scaling

1. IMO it is better to store pointers as you may have different character widths.
2. Store it in the one multidimensional array so no switch statements will be needed.

```
# include <stdio.h>

    char *numbers[10][5] = {{
        "#####",
        "#   #",
        "#   #",
        "#   #",
        "#####",
    },
    {
        "    #",
        "    #",
        "    #",
        "    #",
        "    #",
    }
    ,
    {
        "#####",
        "    #",
        "#####",
        "#    ",
        "#####"
    },
    {
        "#####",
        "    #",
        "#####",
        "    #",
        "#####"
    }
    ,{
        "#   #",
        "#   #",
        "#####",
        "    #",
        "    #"
    }
    ,{
        "#####",
        "#    ",
        "#####",
        "    #",
        "#####"
    },{
        "#####",
        "#    ",
        "#####",
        "#   #",
        "#####"
    },{
        "#####",
        "    #",
        "    #",
        "    #",
        "    #"
    },{
        "#####",
        "#   #",
        "#####",
        "#   #",
        "#####"
    },{
        "#####",
        "#   #",
        "#####",
        "    #",
        "#####"
    }};

void print(const char *str, int scale)
{
    const char *wrk;

    for(int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
    {
        for(int rowrep = 0; rowrep < scale; rowrep++)
        {
            wrk = str;
            while(*wrk)
            {
                char *digitrow = numbers[*wrk - '0'][row];
                while(*digitrow)
                {
                    for(int charrep = 0; charrep < scale; charrep++)
                    {
                        printf("%c", *digitrow);
                    }
                    digitrow++;
                }
                for(int charrep = 0; charrep < scale; charrep++) printf(" ");
                wrk++;
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    print("0136", 1);
    printf("\n");
    print("0136", 2);
    printf("\n");
    print("0136", 3);
    printf("\n");
    print("0136", 6);
}
```

and the result:

```
#####     # ##### ##### 
#   #     #     # #     
#   #     # ##### ##### 
#   #     #     # #   # 
#####     # ##### ##### 

##########          ##  ##########  ##########  
##########          ##  ##########  ##########  
##      ##          ##          ##  ##          
##      ##          ##          ##  ##          
##      ##          ##  ##########  ##########  
##      ##          ##  ##########  ##########  
##      ##          ##          ##  ##      ##  
##      ##          ##          ##  ##      ##  
##########          ##  ##########  ##########  
##########          ##  ##########  ##########  

###############               ###   ###############   ###############   
###############               ###   ###############   ###############   
###############               ###   ###############   ###############   
###         ###               ###               ###   ###               
###         ###               ###               ###   ###               
###         ###               ###               ###   ###               
###         ###               ###   ###############   ###############   
###         ###               ###   ###############   ###############   
###         ###               ###   ###############   ###############   
###         ###               ###               ###   ###         ###   
###         ###               ###               ###   ###         ###   
###         ###               ###               ###   ###         ###   
###############               ###   ###############   ###############   
###############               ###   ###############   ###############   
###############               ###   ###############   ###############   

##############################                              ######      ##############################      ##############################      
##############################                              ######      ##############################      ##############################      
##############################                              ######      ##############################      ##############################      
##############################                              ######      ##############################      ##############################      
##############################                              ######      ##############################      ##############################      
##############################                              ######      ##############################      ##############################      
######                  ######                              ######                              ######      ######                              
######                  ######                              ######                              ######      ######                              
######                  ######                              ######                              ######      ######                              
######                  ######                              ######                              ######      ######                              
######                  ######                              ######                              ######      ######                              
######                  ######                              ######                              ######      ######                              
######                  ######                              ######      ##############################      ##############################      
######                  ######                              ######      ##############################      ##############################      
######                  ######                              ######      ##############################      ##############################      
######                  ######                              ######      ##############################      ##############################      
######                  ######                              ######      ##############################      ##############################      
######                  ######                              ######      ##############################      ##############################      
######                  ######                              ######                              ######      ######                  ######      
######                  ######                              ######                              ######      ######                  ######      
######                  ######                              ######                              ######      ######                  ######      
######                  ######                              ######                              ######      ######                  ######      
######                  ######                              ######                              ######      ######                  ######      
######                  ######                              ######                              ######      ######                  ######      
##############################                              ######      ##############################      ##############################      
##############################                              ######      ##############################      ##############################      
##############################                              ######      ##############################      ##############################      
##############################                              ######      ##############################      ##############################      
##############################                              ######      ##############################      ##############################      
##############################                              ######      ##############################      ##############################
```

https://godbolt.org/z/7exs7j

Add some parameter checking: if the string contains only digirs, if the scale is > 0 etc stc.

In this code character width does not have to be constant. You can create not fixed-width fonts like in this example (look at the digit `1`)

https://godbolt.org/z/Tfv3EP

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    char zero[5][6] = {
        "#####",
        "#   #",
        "#   #",
        "#   #",
        "#####"
    };
    char one[5][6] = {
        "    #",
        "    #",
        "    #",
        "    #",
        "    #"
    };
    char two[5][6] = {
        "#####",
        "    #",
        "#####",
        "#    ",
        "#####"
    };
    char three[5][6] = {
        "#####",
        "    #",
        "#####",
        "    #",
        "#####"
    };
    char four[5][6] = {
        "#   #",
        "#   #",
        "#####",
        "    #",
        "    #"
    };
    char five[5][6] = {
        "#####",
        "#    ",
        "#####",
        "    #",
        "#####"
    };
    char six[5][6] = {
        "#####",
        "#    ",
        "#####",
        "#   #",
        "#####"
    };
    char seven[5][6] = {
        "#####",
        "    #",
        "    #",
        "    #",
        "    #"
    };
    char eight[5][6] = {
        "#####",
        "#   #",
        "#####",
        "#   #",
        "#####"
    };
    char nine[5][6] = {
        "#####",
        "#   #",
        "#####",
        "    #",
        "#####"
    };

    char userInput[3] = "356";
    int n = 3,i,j;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            switch(userInput[j])
            {
                case '0':
                    printf("%s ",zero[i]);
                    break;
                case '1':
                    printf("%s ",one[i]);
                    break;
                case '2':
                    printf("%s ",two[i]);
                    break;
                case '3':
                    printf("%s ",three[i]);
                    break;
                case '4':
                    printf("%s ",four[i]);
                    break;
                case '5':
                    printf("%s ",five[i]);
                    break;
                case '6':
                    printf("%s ",six[i]);
                    break;
                case '7':
                    printf("%s ",seven[i]);
                    break;
                case '8':
                    printf("%s ",eight[i]);
                    break;
                case '9':
                    printf("%s ",nine[i]);
                    break;
            }
            
        }
        printf("\n");
        
    }
}
```

I have changed very little from your code. When you use %s to print a string it searches for '\0' so you must leave one bit blank for '\0'. What I mean by this is. `If your array size is 5. Then you can store 4 characters` in it and last one will be used to store \0.
Since you provided all 5 bits of character your print wont find \0 at the end of every line.

Here is the output:

```
##### ##### #####
    # #     #
##### ##### #####
    #     # #   #
##### ##### #####
```